# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in C# when use tree

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I use a function that save string into a string array
but visual 2012 show this error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is my code :

```
 public void ShowLinkList(ref TreeNode t, ref string[] Data, ref int i)
   {
       string str;
       if (t!= null)
       {
           ShowLinkList(ref t.LeftChild, ref Data, ref i);
           Data[i] = CreatStr(t.Parent.Word) + "," + CreatStr(t.LeftChild.Word )+ "," + CreatStr(t.RightChild.Word) + "," + CreatStr(t.Word);
           i++;
           ShowLinkList(ref t.RightChild, ref Data, ref i);
       }
   }
   public string CreatStr(string str)
   {
       if (str == "")
       {
           return "__";
       }
       return str;
   }
```

when t is null,the "if(t != null)" not allowed compiler to debug
,the CreatStr(string) convert a null string to "__" in output(windows form C#)
this metode (ShowLinkList) saving t.parent.word & t.leftchild.word & t.rightchild.word & t.word in a string array
please help me.thank you

Comment: Where is the object reference exception thrown?

Comment: On what line? my guess is `t.Parent/LeftChild/RightChild` are null... and what does this have to do with html/css?

Comment: Please debug the code and find exact point where this exception is coming, please put the code in try catch.

Comment: Your CreatStr method does not convert a null string, it converts an empty string. Try changing the if to if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: error occur in ths line:

Comment: Data[i] = CreatStr(t.Parent.Word) + "," + CreatStr(t.LeftChild.Word )+ "," + CreatStr(t.RightChild.Word) + "," + CreatStr(t.Word);

Comment: I try to use if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) but not debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `""` is equal to `string.Empty` and *not* equal to `null`

You have no error handling for any of the properties of t so if any of these are null then it won't have a clue what `Word` is, I'd suggest at the very least creating the following method on `TreeNode`

```
public bool HasValidBranches()
{
    return Parent != null && LeftChild != null && RightChild != null;
}
```

then add this to your error handling that is already present and feel free to modify to suit your needs

```
if(t != null && t.HasValidBranches())
....
```

Note: You could always just add the extra null checks directly to the current code.

Comment: I try to use this ..but not debug!!!

Comment: I try to save parent and rightchild and leftchild of a word in a text file

Comment: and maybe compiler not allowed to saving a null value to a string array,because maybe a parent node is null and i try change null to "-" to print at output

Comment: This has nothing to do with trying to save a null value to a string array, you can't concatenate a string to null, and plus I don't think it even gets that far, `Word` is not a property of `null`